# Deployment scanner/folder in JBoss AS7 domain managed mode

Tags: jboss, jboss7.x

Is there a deployment folder where a war can be placed in the master node so that it gets deployed to all the slave nodes in a domain managed setup in JBoss AS7?

I know that we can use the JBoss CLI to deploy to a server group which places the artifact in the JBOSS_HOME/domain/data//content directory.

However I would like to find out if there is a way that it can be placed in a deployments folder under the domain of the master node (e.g. JBOSS_HOME/domain/deployments) that is similar to the one available in the standalone mode (i.e. JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments) so that the deployment scanner picks it up and makes it available to the slave nodes in the domain without the explicit deploy command via CLI.

Comment: No, it would be messy to do that. You should use CLI or DMR or the web management console to deploy to server groups.

Comment: What is the best way then to automate deployment to a managed domain setup from a CI tool. How can I upload a deployment artifact to managed setup via Jenkins or AnthillPro for e.g how can I invoke cli through these tools. Is there a http management API like the JMX API in earlier versions to upload artifacts through scripts.

Comment: There is a maven plugin you could use https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/

Answer (score 2):

To summarize the comments above: There is no deployment directory in domain mode.

- You can use the CLI
- the web console
- the [maven plugin](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/7/plugins/maven/latest/)
- or create your own deployment manager.

I wrote a, now old, [blog post](http://jamezp.blogspot.com/2011/07/jboss-application-server-deployment.html) on how to do this on a standalone server, but it could be slightly changed to use on a domain server. Have a look at how it's done with the [`jboss-as-maven-plugin`](https://github.com/jamezp/jboss-as-maven-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jboss/as/plugin/deployment/domain/DomainDeployment.java) for an example.

Comment: Thanks for the example code  for the Java API. It looks I can get some things done via the non interactive CLI options like start/stop server group/instances  and deploy/undeploy specifying the different options as bash script arguments to reuse it. (https://community.jboss.org/wiki/CLINon-interactiveMode).  However trying to wrap the multiple thngs I want to invoke via the non interactive mode inside a bash script is turning to be slightly verbose. I'll take a look at the dmr API.